# Number of values between input and next highest square

Tags: code-golf, math

Given a positive square number as input. Output the number of values between the input and next highest square.

#### Example

Input: 1

Output: 2

Reason: The numbers 2 and 3 are between 1 and 4, the next highest square

Input: 4

Output: 4

Reason: The numbers 5, 6, 7, 8 are between 4 and 9

Comment: What range of input values do we have to support?

Comment: I think this would have been more interesting if the input didn't have to be a square.

Comment: @xnor Hindsight, I definitely agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
½Ḥ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q3oc7lvz//98SAA)

Port of my Mathematica answer (take square root, then double). This is limited to inputs which can be represented exactly as a floating-point number. If that's an issue, the three-byte solution `Æ½Ḥ` works for arbitrary squares (which Dennis posted first but then deleted).

Comment: Oh I missed the whole "input will be a square" oops.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Me too.  Weird spec IMO.

Comment: Are there any squares that can't be represented exactly in floating point?

Comment: @Christian Sure, floating-point numbers are fixed in size, so there is only a finite number of values they can represent.

Comment: @MartinEnder In that case, given Jelly's support for arbitrary-precision integers and the spec's lack of an upper bound, I vote it should support all valid inputs.

Answer (score 12):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>38</s>, 22 bytes

```
{([[]](({})))}{}([]<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1ojOjo2VkOjulZTU7O2ulYjOtbGTvP/f0MzAA)

I'm *very* proud of this answer. IMO, one of my best brain-flak golfs.

### How does it work?

As many other users have pointed out, the answer is simply *sqrt(n) * 2*. However, calculating the square root in brain-flak is very very nontrivial. Since we know the input will always be a square, we can optimize. So we write a loop that subtracts

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 9...
```

from the input, and track how many times it runs. Once it hits 0, the answer is simply the last number we subtracted minus one.

Originally, I had pushed a counter on to the other stack. However, we can use the main stack itself as a counter, by increasing the stack height.

```
#While TOS (top of stack, e.g. input) != 0:
{

    #Push:
    (

      #The negative of the height of the stack (since we're subtracting)
      [[]]

      #Plus the TOS pushed twice. This is like incrementing a counter by two
      (({}))
    )

#Endwhile
}

#Pop one value off the main stack (or in other words, decrement our stack-counter)
{}

#And push the height of the stack onto the alternate stack
([]<>)
```

In python-y pseudocode, this is basically the following algorithm:

```
l = [input]
while l[-1] != 0:   #While the back of the list is nonzero
    old_len = len(l)
    l.append(l[-1])
    l.append(l[-1] - old_len)

l.pop()

print(len(l))
```

Comment: My brain has literally been flak'd by this, nice job.

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, 8 bytes

```
2Sqrt@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfKLiwqMRBWe1/moK@g4JGUGJeemq0oUFsnJGmgr6@QkBRZl7JfwA) (Using Mathics.)

The difference between **n<sup>2</sup>** and **(n+1)<sup>2</sup>** is always **2n+1** but we just want the values between them excluding both ends, which is **2n**.

This can potentially be shortened to `2#^.5&` depending on precision requirements.

Comment: How about 2√#& ?

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 8 bytes

```julia
!n=2n^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVRCkBAFAXQb1ZxKUU9yjDKB1mIlGJqpEsy63@cn3OE069WNeFguFRW3fWA8EReC1pBL6g7gbGCpiviaLofz9flaWYCyhF/M1MBBQmLeOemHw)

Answer (score 2):

## dc, 5

```
?2*vp
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnYKhgomBprZCSz6UABAVFmXklaQpKqsUKunYKSgoqMKVg2dTkjHyEkEKNQkqygm6qgvp/eyOtsoL/6lwp@Xmp/w).

---

Previously I misread the question.  This version works for any positive integer input, not just perfect squares:

## dc, 12

```
?dv1+d*1-r-p
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RYpBCoAgFAX3nuIhhVC4ENoFdRbz/8iNikqr7m4RRLOcmc2Wo@0xo3KpzhaGDzCYZlAUeEjZh7pD9gV6gUT3jW9ld8Rf4QI5aIZqK51mpMHorFNTgmLgdgM).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*I missed the "input will be square" caveat, but this will work for all non-negative integers...* [Martin Ender already gave the 2 byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126684/53748).

```
½‘Ḟ²’_
```

A monadic link returning the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//wr3igJjhuJ7CsuKAmV////80)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
¬*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9AaLaP//y0B)

Square root of the input, then multiply by 2.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 20 bytes

*Shout out to DJMcMayhem's amazing (albiet slightly longer) answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126676/number-of-values-between-input-and-next-highest-square/126704#126704)*

```
{({}()[({}()())])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1qjulZDMxpMamhqxmrWVtf@/29oYgIA)

### Explanation

This code works by counting down from the square number by odd increments.  Since every square is the sum of consecutive odd numbers this will reach 0 in n<sup>1/2</sup> steps.  The trick here is we actually keep track of our steps in an *even* number and use a static `()` to offset it to the appropriate odd number.  Since the answer is 2n<sup>1/2</sup>, this even number will be our answer.  So when we reach 0 we remove the zero and our answer is sitting there on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
(Sqrt@#+1)^2-#-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfI7iwqMRBWdtQM85IV1nXUO1/QFFmXomCQ5qCgyEXgm3yHwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>25</s> 10 bytes

```matlab
@(n)2*n^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0/TSCsvTs/0f5qGoSZXmoaJ5n8A)

Saved 15 bytes by using Martin's much better approach. The range consists of `2*sqrt(n)` elements. The function does exactly that: Multiplies `2` with the root of the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
+?
_
S
+1
^2
-1
-G
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bniueK07PlEvbkCvOiEvXkEvXncv//3@T/4YA)

Do you want to know how it works? Well, fear not! I'm here to educate you!

```
+?   Add the input to x (the accumulator)
_    Store the input in the input list
S    Square root
+1   Add 1
^2   Square
-1   Subtract 1
-G   Subtract the input
O    Output as number
```

Comment: I had the same logic for my original QBIC answer, but there's [a shorter way](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bniueK07PlEvbkCvOiEvXkEvXncv//3@T/4YA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
½‘R²Ṫ_‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q3kcNM4IObXq4c1U8kPX//38TAA)

Explanation:

```
½‘R²Ṫ_    Input:              40
½         Square root         6.32455532...
 ‘        Increment           7.32455532...
  R       Range               [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
   ²      Square              [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
    Ṫ     Tail                49
     _‘   Subtract input+1    8
```

Comment: Btw, the input will always be a square itself.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fixed

Comment: @MartinEnder I totally misread the challenge, then... in the interest of not copying your answer (since it's obvious now why that works) I'll leave this one up.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 16 bytes

```python
lambda n:2*n**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPykgrT0tLz/R/Wn6RQqZCZp6CoY6JFZcCEBQUZeaVaChV1yro2ilU1yrpAZXkJpZoZOoopGlkampq/gcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
√d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//UceslP//TQA)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript ES6, 10 bytes

```
n=>n**.5*2
```

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=javascript-node&p=y0ktUUizVciztcvT0tIz1TLi4krOzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTMNTUtEYTMgEK/QcA) `Math.sqrt` is pretty long which is why we use `**.5`

Comment: Then that's ES7 rather than ES6...

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 3 bytes

```
2√(Ans
```

Simplest approach...

Answer (score 1):

## MATL (<s>8</s> 7 bytes)

I'm sure this can be reduced significantly (edit: thanks Luis), but a naive solution is:

```
X^QUG-q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyIuMNRdt/D/fyNTAA)

### Explanation:

```
X^   % Take the square root of the input (an integer)
QU  % Square the next integer to find the next square
G-   % Subtract the input to find the difference
q    % Decrement solution by 1 to count only "in between" values.
```

Comment: You can replace `2^`  by `U` (and this [worked in version 20.1.1](https://matl.suever.net/?code=X%5EQUG-q&inputs=1&version=20.1.1), which was the most recent at the time of the challenge, so the answer it would be eligible even by our old standard)

Comment: Thanks Luis! I'm surprised that my naive approach only wasted 1 character relative to the MATL master. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
t·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5ND2//8tuQA)

Another port of Martin Ender's submission ...

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>19</s> 9 bytes

```
?sqr(:)*2
```

*Saved a bunch by copying @MartinEnder's approach.*

No TIO link for QBIC, unfortunately.

### Explanation

```
?          PRINT
 sqr( )    The square root of
     :     the input
        *2 doubled
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 9 bytes

```
n->2*n^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9fOSCsvTs/0f0FRZl6JRpqGoabmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

```php
<?=count(range($argn,(sqrt($argn)+1)**2))-2;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkomTNZW8HFLNNzi/NK9EoSsxLT9UAS@poFBcWlUDYmtqGmlpaRpqaukbW//9/zcvXTU5MzkgFAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
2/*<ER
o@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99IX8vGNYgr3yHz/39LAA)

#### Explanation

Again, computes **2 sqrt(n)**. The layout saves two bytes over the standard solution:

```
/o
\i@/2RE2*
```

Breakdown of the code, excluding redirection of the IP:

```
2    Push 2 for later.
i    Read all input.
i    Try reading more input, pushes "".
2    Push 2.
R    Negate to get -2.
E    Implicitly discard the empty string and convert the input to an integer.
     Then take the square root of the input. E is usually exponentiation, but
     negative exponents are fairly useless in a language that only understands
     integers, so negative exponents are interpreted as roots instead.
*    Multiply the square root by 2.
o    Output the result.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 56 bytes

```go
import."math"
func f(n float64)float64{return 2*Sqrt(n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCoNADEX3c4owq6QLoUV6jkJPEMTYoU7GhrgSzz5a666rz3883lDqxN2bhx4yJw0pT8UcomSP9XeamNlfMcisHQgqyFjY7y2du1jvsyncLs@POSqt9VC/PaQlAMBeax6W1EdFwSvRP2x3uNYN)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

<sup>Crossed out 4 is still 4 :c</sup>

```
t2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/xEjr/38TAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 3 bytes

```
√2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9Rxywjrf//TQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 21 bytes

```
.+
$*
(^1?|11\1)+
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLI87QvsbQMMZQE8g15Pr/39DAAAA) Explanation: Works by taking the square root of the number based on @MartinEnder's triangular number solver. After matching the square number, `$1` is the difference between the square number and the previous square number, in unary. We want the next difference, but exclusive, which is just 1 more. To achieve this, we count the number of null strings in `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```
+@UOI0),c?;^..u;;/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/1/bIdTf00BTJ9neOk5Pr9TaWv//f0sA)

[Watch it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=K0BVT0kwKSxjPzteLi51Ozsv&input=OQ==&speed=5)

A port of [Martin Ender's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126680/67312). Since Cubix only supports integer arithmetic, computing the square root is literally just trying every number until we hit the square root, so this approach only works since the input is a perfect square.

Expands to the following cube:

```
    + @
    U O
I 0 ) , c ? ; ^
. . u ; ; / . .
    . .
    . .
```

```
I       # read in input [n^2]
0       # push 0 [n^2, 0]
Main loop:
)       # increment [n^2, 1]
,       # divide, rounding to zero [n^2, 1, n^2]
c       # bitwise xor -- zero if equal, positive if not
?       # turn right if positive, go straight if zero [n^2,1,n^2,___]
 nonzero branch:
  /      # reflect IP direction
  ;;     # pop top two off stack [n^2, 1]
  u      # right-hand U-turn
  (re-enter main loop)
 zero branch: stack is [n^2, n, n, 0]
  ;      # pop top of stack [n^2, n, n]
  ^      # go north
  +      # add top two elements [n^2, n, n, 2n]
  U      # left-hand u-turn
  O      # output as int
  @      # terminate program
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 22 bytes

```
SELECT 2*SQRT(a)FROM t
```

Input is via a pre-existing table, [per our standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) / JShell, 17 bytes

```java
n->2*Math.sqrt(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBTsMwDL3nK3xM0RZpEyBNhZ0QEodx6RFxCGm6pqROSdyNCfXbS@jaqRLzIU6e/d6zU8mDXLpGY5V/bnpTN84TVBEULRkrMiURtU/Zv0rRoiLjULwgPY/3lLGm/bBGgbIyBNhJg/DDIMaIB5IU08GZHOpY5Rl5g/u3d5B@H5Kx@S9GZwhjfgTUxwnl2SmQroXBJL0wjqWxGvhIEKUMr/qb4ng8mQsP4me6a0k00Z8sciWt4j0ut@ubnaRShC9PHJN@MU0g8KI2M@3Y@byyZO7iU8MgPPukh6cB30KxgGgNOB/Oa2o9QiFk09gTn9brWNev4BY2sLqH9d0v)

Note: This would require `import java.util.function.*;` to get `IntFunction<T>` in Java 8 or Java 9, but the `java.util.function` package is imported by default in JShell.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 9 bytes

```
(*2).sqrt
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X0PLSFOvuLCo5H9uYmaegq1CZl5JalFicomCioKGkRZUDgA)

Input and output will be treated as Float values.

Answer (score 0):

## Noether, 7 bytes

```
I.5^2*P
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=SS41XjIqUA)

Just the same as every other answer: outputs two times the square root.

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 26 bytes

```
readIO
i=2*i^.5
printInt i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/78oNTHF058r09ZIKzNOz5SroCgzr8Qzr0Qh8////yYA)

Straightforward port of Martin Ender's Mathematica answer.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 24 bytes

```c#
n=>System.Math.Sqrt(n)*2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 12 bytes

```perl6
*.sqrt.Int*2
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##PY27CsIwAEX3fMWlBEmCBuvgYKm7P9ESYoqFvkxSoYg/1dWt/@Qca1Hne849nbHVPvTO4LaXOiH1gJVuzwZpENJdrZenxotdSAgpWgsWSxlv@fScRtwJMOPUGlUhhalM7UBzZFJmKErrPIM40ny9WILLWnVMTCMHT/6q6ys/y58ko/kyODUgKpuu9/PbAV/mx7KlxyPyCK@m3WilL@YN)

---

If it had to work with positive numbers that aren't squares:

```perl6
{+($_^..^(.sqrt.Int+1)²)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##PY1LDoIwAAX3nOKFNKYFbcQFCwnuvQSkwRJNyse2mBDCpTyCd3JdC1HX781ML7VK3WAkHimvsqAZsam6i0TuppiSsuC8oNzcteXn1sYJez3Z7OpOI@H8sMcUAJ4hWgqFHFLJxoCUWDjUN20sRXQi5RbUAxHjjehp5CVg2R81g7IeXro@uQ5GjAhvbT9Ybzvi@/l96dpjYTC7d9vtKlFd5Qc)

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ri_mQ)_*-~
```

Explanation:

```
ri e# Read integer: | 16
_  e# Duplicate:    | 16 16
mQ e# Square root:  | 16 4
)  e# Increment:    | 16 5
_* e# Square:       | 16 25
-  e# Subtract:     | -9
~  e# Bitwise NOT:  | 8
```

### Alternative Solution, 6 bytes

```
rimQ2*
```

Explanation:

```
ri e# Read integer: | 16
mQ e# Square root:  | 4
2* e# Times 2:      | 8
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Pyth, 4 bytes**

```
y@Q2
```

Explanation:

```
     # Implicit copy input to Q
y    # Multiply by 2
 @Q2 # Square-root of Q
     # Implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
Ｉ×²ＸＮ·⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9jaGFyY29hbP//77ypw5fCsu@8uO@8rsK34oG1//8xMTI1ODk5OTA2ODQyNjI0)

### Explanation

```
Ｉ         Cast (int -> str)
  ×²       Multiplied by 2
    ＸＮ·⁵ N to the power of .5 (Square root of N)
```

Comment: @DestructibleLemon No? The output is always a whole number (`something.0`)

Comment: counter example: 66 and 2. wait a minute I didn't read the challenge very well nvm

Comment: @DestructibleLemon "Given a positive square number as input"

Answer (score 0):

**C#, 42 bytes**

```
int b=(int)Math.Sqrt(n);b=(b+1)*(b+1)-n-1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/xEjr/38TAA)

Comment: Can't it just the last assignment just be `b=(b+1)*(b+1)-n-1`?

Comment: You could do this: `int b=1+(int)Math.sqrt(n);b=b*b-n-1;`
Doesn't this need to be a Lambda or something?

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 6 bytes

```
2×*∘.5
```

I can't believe this hasn't been posted yet.
A variant with the same byte count:

```
+⍨*∘.5
```

Both of them work by doubling the square root.

Answer (score 0):

## [NewStack](https://github.com/LyamBoylan/NewStack/), 3 bytes

```
2√ᵢ
```

### The breakdown:

```
 √ᵢ    Append the square root of the input.
2      Multiply it by two.
```

### Why this works:

To find how many numbers `N` are in between the square number `x` and the next square number `m`, we first need to find a formula for `m`.

Since `x` is a square number, `√x` will be an integer. And `√x + 1` will equal `√m`.

Therefore `m` = `(√x + 1)^2` = `x + 2√x + 1`

The amount of numbers in between `x` and `m` will just equal their difference minus 1.

`N` = `m - x - 1` = `(x + 2√x + 1) - x - 1`

So we've concluded

`N` = `2√x`

Answer (score 0):

## [Plain English](https://github.com/Folds/english) <s>129</s> 98 bytes

```
To put a n number's d into a r number:
Put the square root of the n in the r.
Add the r to the r.
```

Ungolfed:

```
To put a number's delta into a result number:
Put the square root of the number in the result.
Add the result to the result.
```

The Plain English IDE is available at [github.com/Folds/english](https://github.com/Folds/english).  The IDE runs on Windows.  It compiles to 32-bit x86 code.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 4 bytes

```
+:%:

    e.g. +:%: 9  ====>  6
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 9 bytes

```
=2*A1^0.5
```

---

To handle all cases (not only squares):  21 bytes

```
=INT(A1^0.5+1)^2-A1-1
```